# Football Manager game fails on Ubuntu 18.04 with wine

Tags: wine, games

[Football Manager 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_Manager_2018) fails on Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed wine and also downloaded the game, but it didn't start when launched.

Comment: If you try to run it from Terminal, what errors do you get?

Comment: For tips, see https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#When_I_double-click_on_a_.exe_file_in_my_file_manager.2C_nothing_happens  Note: This game is not listed in WineHQ database: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=application&sReturnToTitle=Browse%20Applications&sTitle=Browse+Applications&iItemsPerPage=200&iPage=2&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=false

Comment: I think the reason it is hard to find wine support for FM18 is because a linux version was available. Are you sure that the version you downloaded is only for windows?